# How to get first-child of element using $(this) in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div id="idname">
<div class="badge">
  <div class="icon abc_badge"></div>
  <div class="badges_info">
   <h4>some text</h4>
  </div>
 </div>
<div class="badge">
  <div class="icon xyz_badge"></div>
  <div class="badges_info">
   <h4>some more text</h4>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".badge").click(function () {
            var a = $(this+':first-child');
            var iconDiv = a.html();
            alert(iconDiv);
        });
    });
</script>
```

In above jquery code I want `<div class="icon abc_badge"></div>` of each `div` having class `badge`.
In short I want first child of each div this reference to `$(this)` .

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply **[.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find)** here, so use:

```
var a = $(this).find(':first-child');
```

instead of:

```
var a = $(this+':first-child');
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3sLG4/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use `children()` in combo with `first()`.

```
$(this).children().first()
```

> The .children() method differs from .find() in that .children() only
>   travels a single level down the DOM tree while .find() can traverse
>   down multiple levels to select descendant elements (grandchildren,
>   etc.) as well.

From https://api.jquery.com/children/

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".badge").click(function () {
        var a = $(this).find(':first-child');
        var iconDiv = a.text();
        alert(iconDiv);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use children nth child like below :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".badge").click(function () {
            var a = $(this).children(':nth-child(0)');
            var iconDiv = a.html();
            alert(iconDiv);
        });
    });
</sctipt>
```

OR call `first()` on `children()`

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".badge").click(function () {
                var a = $(this).children().first();
                var iconDiv = a.html();
                alert(iconDiv);
            });
        });
    </sctipt>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need the outerHTML:

*Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/w3Js2/1/*

```
$(".badge").click(function () {
    var $a = $(this).find(':first-child');
    var h = $a[0].outerHTML;
    alert(h);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Having a look at `jQuery.find()` [code here](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=jQuery.find) it seems that `.find()` is then translated in [jQuery Selector Context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context)..

*This Code works*

```
var a = $(':first-child',this);
```

<kbd>***[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5A7cs/)***</kbd>